# Auto-resize popup window

Tags: java, javascript, html, window

I have a popup window that is launched with a WxL dimension, where W = width, and L = length.

The content fits well in that area for a few screens. However, in some cases (views that appear conditionally), the window size is not big enough and ends up showing a scrollbar.

The ask here is - How can we auto-adjust the popup window size so that it resizes itself (based on the content), and hence avoid the scrollbar in all cases.

One crude option is to get the max size of all possible views that can appear within the window and always (pre)set that as the size of the window, i.e., something like (W+w)x(L+l). However, that's not ideal/preferable since some of the views do not have much content in them and would look awkward with a larger popup size.

Comment: you can set min and max height for normal screen..If it exceeds u can wil calculate dynamically and set the height..the height should be auto is fine

Answer (score 0):

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tF8TU/2/)

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
    // get the screen height and width  
    var maskHeight = $(window).height();  
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    // calculate the values for center alignment
    var dialogTop =  (maskHeight  - $('#dialog-box').height())/2;  
    var dialogLeft = (maskWidth - $('#dialog-box').width())/2; 

    // assign values to the overlay and dialog box
    $('#dialog-overlay').css({ height:$(document).height(), width:$(document).width() }).show();
    $('#dialog-box').css({ top: dialogTop, left: dialogLeft, position:"fixed"}).show();
    }).resize();
});
```